# How to find a know signal in another signal which contains other signals along with the signal i need in python

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, demodulation, bpsk, synchronization

I am working on BPSK with sound waves a carrier waves.

Actually I am modulating my data with some known sync bits along with the information I need to send. **So the things I will be having at demodulation side is these sync bits and carrier wave.**

So I am modulating these sync bits with carrier and **cross correlating** this modulated (over sync bits) wave with received wave at the transmiter. By doing this I want **to find the exact time position** (where these sync bits appear in received wave).

For this I am first crosscorelating received wave and my sync wave then, when I plot it I wil surely get a maximum where the sync wave in both signals coincide.

**But I am not sure if this maximum is the position I need (when there is a DC offset or large amplitudes in the received signal, it can also create an extreme value)**

So to overcome this, I autocorelated my sync wave with itself and took the
**absolute difference between the all the values of crosscorelated matrix and
autocorelated value. Then I assumed which ever value has the least value as the
synced location.**

This is also not working (I think as iam not sure that
the location iam getting is midpoint of sync or starting of sync). Is this
approach correct?

**Or are there any other approaches to find the starting sync position in received wave?**

I also needed help in knowing whether if we use the first method (wher evr maxima comes in crosscorelation taking tht as sync location) is this location I got, is sync starting location or midpoint of sync?

Comment: Sai Teja- How long can your sync bit sequence be? See this posting, perhaps that can help you?  http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30824/what-are-the-advantages-of-barker-sequence-over-marker-sequnce/30842#30842

Comment: Dan Boschen- yesterday i found that my sync bit sequence is too short to give a significant peak in cross correlation, now i increased my sync bits to 1000 (where my data bits are 7000) which is giving me exact sync location, just by finding the max value of cross correlation will give mid point of my sync sequence, as i knew the sync sequence length i can figure out data start time stamp (as my data begins right after sync ends).  thanks

Comment: Very good. Generally if your noise is white, you are getting a 10Log10(N) advantage in SNR due to the correlation processing, where N is the number of sync bits. Knowing your SNR conditions and probability of detection you can then design how long your sync bit sequence would need to be.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little research on detecting the `sync_start` location on my received signal.

First I modulated the bits (`sync_start` bits + data bits + `sync_end` bits) with a sine signal as my carrier, with a **frequency of $20 \text{ kHz}$ and a total length of 10000 bits** (including both `sync_start` and `sync_end`).

I then converted this modulated wave into a *.wav* file 
and played it on my PC, while recording simultaniously on an another PC, using *Pyaudio* (Python). That gave me a recorded *.wav* - my received signal.

Now as I knew my sync bits value, I modulated them on the same carrier wave and cross correlated this with the received wave.

## Case 1:

$\text{bit length} = 10000$ (including `sync_start` and `sync_end`),

$\text{number of sync_start bits} = \text{sync_end} = 2287$

The plot of cross correlation is as shown :

[image: Case 1 xcorr]

## Case 2:

$\text{bit length} = 15000$

[image: case 2 xcorr]

## case 3:

$\text{bit length} = 20000$

[image: case 3 xcorr]

As the data length increases(keeping our `sync_start` and `sync_end` same in all cases), the exact time stamps of `sync_start_mid` index and `sync_end_mid` index gets more accurate.

***Note :*** For data bits here, I took all of them as $1$'s -- that might be the reason for the smaller amplitudes in the middle. I will add random data and see if I am getting the same inference.

Please correct me if there is any mistake in my inference. As far as now I am now able to exactly pinpoint the synchronization between transmitted and received waves.

I also wanted to know the limitations of length of the sync bits (because when my sync bits length gets smaller, the dominant peak location cannot be found from cross correlation).

And I am using a **BPSK** scheme.

Comment: Sai Teja- See my comment above on SNR vs length. This holds assuming the noise from one symbol to the next are independent: When you sum two symbols for example, the signal of interest doubles (in magnitude) but the noise standard deviation will only increase by the square root of 2. Hence the 10Log10(N) increase in SNR.